# Replace values in one array that are contained in another without iterating through every single record

Tags: c#

I am creating a Spotify Playlist generator via scraping the a festival's website artists page. I am able to return all of the artist names but some of them don't link up to the Spotify search term e.g:

```
Festival Artist Name: "Slash and..."
Spotify Search Term:  "Slash"
```

I have created an object called `EdgeCases`:

```
public int EdgeCasesID { get; set; }
public int FestivalID { get; set; }
public string ComparableString { get; set; }
public string SearchTerm { get; set; }
public bool Skip { get; set; }
```

It represents all the data needed to replace/skip/search for that artist that doesn't really match up with the Spotify search term.

The code I currently have compares all edge cases to all artists pulled from the web page; I just want help with how to reduce code + comparisons

```
foreach (string artist in artistNames)
{
    bool skipArtist = false;
    SearchItem searchItem = null;

    // Check if any of those artists exist in the UnfoundArtists database
    // More or less check if the name is different on Spotify or if they are even on Spotify
    foreach (EdgeCase unfoundArtist in EdgeCases)
    {
        // If the download artist page contains the a specific name 
        // e.g if 'slash & the conspirators' contains 'slash'
        if (artist.Trim().Contains(unfoundArtist.ComparableString)) 
        { 
            // If so, check if the artist is on Spotify
            if (unfoundArtist.ToSearch)
            {
                // search using SearchTerm
            }

            // This case is if the artist is on the page but not on Spotify
            skipArtist = true;
        }
        else
        {
            // Search the artist if there is no edge case - different Spotify 
            // name/on Spotify at all etc
            searchItem = _api.SearchItems(artist.Trim(), SearchType.Artist, limit: 1);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: we need to break out of the inner loop if the if condition returns true, right?

Comment: Get the artist.Trim() out of the inner loop.  You are going to calculate this every time the inner loop runs, and the value will never change in that loop.

Comment: Honestly this sounds like a better fit for some [RegEx](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/regular-expressions) patterns. Create some reg ex patterns to capture all your edge cases and put them in the correct artist.